# Arguments passed to the command line not printed and the program loops indefinitely

Tags: c++, linux, unix, operating-system

I'm trying to implement a simple command line program that takes three arguments and prints them on the linux terminal

For example:

```
>c++ exec.cpp

>./a 32 + 32
```

Should print out contents like this

32

+

32

But the program is looping indefinitely

I've implemented a check for argc
Like this

```
if(argc!=3) {
cout << "Exit" << endl;
return -9999;
}
```

In case the argument count is 3

These lines of code should be executed

```
else {
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
cout << argv[i] << endl;
}
}
```

But as I explained before the program loops indefinitely

EDIT:
Since I was asked to post the entire code here it is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
 if(argc!=3) {
    cout << "Exit" << endl;
    return -9999;
    }
else {
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your entire program, not just individual snippits.  No one can infer the problem from what you have shown so far.

Comment: also invoking `./a 32 + 32` is 4 arguments and `argc` will be `4`. Not three.  The program command itself, `"./a"`, is always `argv[0]`.

Comment: Learn some debugging ;) It's tough at first but the principle is simple: Imagine step by step what you think happens and verify that's actually the case. IDEs have "breakpoints" for that purpose, but the easiest way is to insert more couts. For example check how many arguments you actually got by writing: cout << argc << endl;

Comment: Or better use cerr instead of cout, because cout uses a buffer which might not actually end up on screen if the program literally crashes right after.

Comment: @selbie I didn't post the entire program because the last time I did that it was frowned upon by the stack overflow community but if you need it I'll add it in the post

Comment: @AlexGeorg alright I'll give it a try :)

Comment: @Ammar What we need to properly answer a question is this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexGeorg Thank you I'll bookmark that page for future reference :)

Comment: @selbie I've edited in the source code you can take a look now

Comment: are you sure it's in a loop. it should just exit print `Exit` and exit as `argc!=3` is `true`. see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aedf75b27af0125e)

Comment: Exit prints but problem is with the loop it doesnt print anything,furthermore program just loops indefinitely without printing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working...
I made slight modifications (eg. argc !=4 , i <= argc , etc. )
I compiled it using gcc (g++) on my linux system using:

```
g++ exec.cpp -o a.out
./a.out
```

Output:

```
Exit
```

When I run:

```
./a.out 4 + 3
```

Output:

```
4
+
3
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for

Comment: @Ammar: you can let everyone know that by clicking the accept checkbox under the vote arrows. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Now with code, that does look okey to me in fact.
There doesn't seem to be a way to have an endless loop in every case.
What happens if you add `return(0);` to the very end of the main function?

`Main` always has to return something and compilers normally either complain or do that on their own hwoever if the propgrammer didn't add it.

Oh, have you tried the `cerr` variant instead of `cout` for your error message? Because returning from the main right after, is quite the same as the crash I mentioned.

Comment: `main` is guaranteed by the C++ standard to return 0 if you don't explicitly write that. If a compiler doesn't do that it's not standard conforming.

Comment: Not working and i dont even get any output just indefinite loop

Comment: Your argc must be 4... The file name is also taken as an argument...

Comment: @Ammar How do you know you have an infinite loop if you don't get any output? Fear there is something wrong with the way you are compiling your project or how you execute the file. I'd suggest starting the project anew in a new directory only copying the pure text of the code.

Comment: @AlexGeorg It's hard to explain for me since I'm not a native english speaker but I know that because the program never stops executing and I'm never prompted to enter anything to the linux terminal again I have to Press CTRL + c to stop the execution of the program